# On finitely generated R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated R-module and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $IM=M$. Then prove there exists $a\in I$ such that $(1-a)M=0$.

Thanks

Comment: Yes R has an identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of a generalization of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. It can be proved as follows:

Let $(m_1,\ldots,m_n)$ be a generating system for $M$. Since $M = IM$, we can write $m_j = \sum_i a_{ij} m_i$ with $a_{ij} \in I$. Considering $M^n$ as an $\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$-module in the obvious way, we have 
$$(1_n-A) \left(\begin{matrix}m_1\\ \vdots \\ m_n \end{matrix}\right) = 0$$
where $A = (a_{ij})$. Multiply this with the adjugate matrix of $(1_n-A)$ to get
$$\det(1_n -A)M = 0.$$
Now expand the determinant using the Leibniz Rule. This gives an $a \in I$ with $(1-a)M = 0$.

Comment: I was thinking of the more general version that says that an endomorphism $\phi$ of $M$ with $\phi(M) \subset IM$ satisfies a monic algebraic relation over $I$. The above is the special case $\phi = 1_M$. I edited my answer and called it "a special case of a generalization" (these do not cancel out).

Comment: That makes sense, then :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of Nakayama's lemma, as stated in statement 1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma), and which you can find a proof for in zillions of places if you search for "proof of Nakayama's lemma". (That includes this link itself.)

---

To be clear, that statement says "There exists an  $r$, $1-r\in I$ and $fM=0$. If you take $a=1-r$, you have your $a$.